# Remove excessive whitespace from string

Tags: c++, strings

Is that standards-compliant?

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

std::string remove_excessive_ws(std::string const &str)
{
    std::string result{ str };
    auto end{ std::remove_if(std::begin(result), std::end(result),
                             [](std::string::value_type const &ch) {
                                  return std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned>(ch)) &&
                                         (std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned>((&ch)[1])) || (&ch)[1] == '\0');
                             }
              )
    };
    result.erase(end, std::end(result));
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char const *foo{ "Hello              World!       " };
    std::cout << '\"' << remove_excessive_ws(foo) << "\"\n";
}
```

I'm unsure whether I should be accessing `(&ch)[1]`. I think it should be legal, but I am not sure. After all, `std::remove_if()` could copy the character and pass it to the function, so the pointer `(&ch) + 1` might not be valid.

Comment: It's not standard (but you should have asked this question on stack overflow instead, code review is for working code). `std:string` is not required to end with a null character and dereferencing the end iterator is undefined behavior; if your input ends with a space, it's precisely what you'll end up doing.

Comment: I don't think `std::remove_if()` is allowed to make a copy of each element - if it did, it couldn't (sensibly) work with containers of move-only values.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yay, that's reasonable! :)

Comment: Please clarify, does or doesn't the current code work as intended?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Define the problem

It's not clear from the description what's considered "excessive" whitespace.  From experimenting, it seems that the idea is to collapse multiple whitespace to a single whitespace character, except at the end of the string, where whitespace is to be completely removed.  (Whitespace at the beginning of string seems to treated the same as inner whitespace).  It's also not clear which whitespace character should be kept - the example code keeps the last one, but is that a requirement, or just an implementation choice?

## Missing include

`std::begin()` and `std::end()` are declared in `<iterator>`.  However, there's no reason not to use the `begin()` and `end()` member functions of `std::string` here, as we're not operating on generic values.

## When an argument is to be copied, pass by value

We don't need to copy `str` into `result`:

```
std::string remove_excessive_ws(std::string str)
```

## Bug

Like all the `<cctype>` functions, `std::isspace()` requires that its argument be either `EOF` or representable as `unsigned char`.  Converting a (possibly signed) `char` direct to `unsigned int` can sign-extend to an out-of-range value.  We need to convert `char` to `unsigned char` before widening to `unsigned int`:

```
static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)
```

## Bug

Prior to C++11, accessing the character after the end of the string is undefined behaviour (C++11 requires an extra null to follow the string data).  Thankfully, it's easy to avoid this bug by simply remembering whether the last character seen was a space.

Here's a C++11 version:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

std::string remove_excessive_ws(std::string str)
{
    bool seen_space = false;
    auto end{ std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
                             [&seen_space](unsigned char ch) {
                                 bool is_space = std::isspace(ch);
                                 std::swap(seen_space, is_space);
                                 return seen_space && is_space;
                             })};
    // adjust end to remove end whitespace
    if (end != str.begin() && std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(end[-1]))) {
        --end;
    }
    str.erase(end, str.end());
    return str;
}
```

We might want to move `seen_space` into the lambda expression in later C++ versions that allow that.

This also is more readable, as we can perform the widening to `unsigned int` when calling the lambda, rather than having to write a cast.

Style-wise, I'd normally prefer to name the lambda, and keep the erase-remove call on a single line so that the idiom is obvious:

```
// Assuming C++17 now
std::string remove_excessive_ws(std::string s)
{
    auto is_doubled_space =
        [seen_space=false](unsigned char c) mutable {
            return std::exchange(seen_space, std::isspace(c))
                && seen_space;
        };
    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), is_doubled_space), s.end());
    // remove trailing whitespace
    if (!s.empty() && std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(s.back()))) {
        s.pop_back();
    }
    // convert all whitespace into ordinary space character
    std::replace_if(s.begin(), s.end(),
                    [](unsigned char c) { return std::isspace(c); }, ' ');
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Personally I try really hard to avoid mutating lambdas. Unfortunately for this problem this would preclude using `std::remove_if`. Instead, some kind of reduction or prefix scan would need to be used, and is probably not as efficient.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point @Konrad - `mutable` lambdas are harder to reason about.  It might be that a plain old `for (auto it = str.begin();  it != str.end();  ++it)` loop (followed by `erase`) may actually be the clearest code.  But it's good to see a few options to choose from!

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string remove_excessive_ws(std::string const &str)
{
    std::string result{ str };
```

As Toby mentioned, if you plan on copying and mutating the copy locally, you should pass the parameter `str` by value. It should also be noted that `result` will have the same capacity as `str` and won't shrink to fit automatically (or take advantage of SSO if allocated).

---

```
std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned>(ch))
```

Be aware that [`std::isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) removes spaces (`' '`), whitespaces (`'\n', '\v', '\f', '\r'`), and tabs (`'\t'`).

You should cast to `unsigned char`.

---

```
(std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned>((&ch)[1])) || (&ch)[1] == '\0')
```

> Is that standards-compliant?

Using the [built-in subscript operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) on a pointer is standards compliant. From the C++17 standard (n4659), [Postfix Expressions § 8.2.1 Subscripting](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.sub#1):

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a postfix expression. One of the expressions shall be a [glvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) of type “array of `T`” or a [prvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) of type “pointer to `T`” and the other shall be a [prvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) of unscoped enumeration or integral type.

When accessing memory out of bounds via the built-in subscript operator, the behavior is undefined. A well-defined approach would be to track the next index and access the next element using `std::string::operator[]` (element at `size()` returns `CharT{}`). `std::string` is not a null-terminated sequence and considers the null character (`CharT{}`) to be a valid character within a sequence.

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
std::string str = "a\0b"s;
std::cout << str << '\n'; // prints "ab"
```

---

For a standard library solution on removing duplicates, I would simply pass the predicate to [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique). No pointer arithmetic is necessary. Just pass it a binary predicate that checks if both characters are whitespaces:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

std::string remove_excessive_ws(std::string s)
{
    static auto const space_space =
        [](unsigned char a, unsigned char b) {
            return std::isspace(a) && std::isspace(b);
        };

    s.erase(std::unique(s.begin(), s.end(), space_space), s.end());

    // trim final space
    if (!s.empty() && std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(s.back()))) {
        s.pop_back();
    }

    return s;
}
```

Your function leaves a leading whitespace if one or more exists. Is this intended? Should there be a common character (single space) to merge the different characters `std::isspace` catches? If the ultimate goal was to trim all outer whitespace and join non-whitespace tokens with single spaces, I would use abseil's [`absl::StrSplit()`](https://abseil.io/tips/10) and [`absl::StrJoin()`](https://abseil.io/tips/36). The resulting string would either take advantage of SSO if small enough or use a more appropriate capacity.

```
// remove_excess_whitespace
//
// Trims leading and trailing space, whitespace, and tab characters
// such that the resulting string is single space separated.
std::string remove_excess_whitespace(absl::string_view sv) {
    return absl::StrJoin(absl::StrSplit(sv, ' ', absl::SkipWhitespace{}), " ");
}
```

Comment: *Be aware that std::isspace removes spaces (' '), whitespaces ('\n', '\v', '\f', '\r'), and tabs ('\t')* – that's intended.

Comment: *As for std::string, this behavior is well-defined* – yes, but what about `remove_if()`, is it guaranteed that it won't copy?

Comment: `std::remove_if` copies individual characters that do not satisfy the predicate. The well-defined behavior I was talking about is accessing `str[str.size()]`. So, instead of checking `&ch[1] == '\0'`, keep an index to the next variable and use `str[index]` (or better, use `std::unique` and don't worry about subscript access for adjacent elements).

Comment: I was talking about `remove_if()` probably copying the element before passing it to the predicate.

Comment: Compilers are pretty good at inlining arguments and lambda predicates. I would be concerned with unnecessary heap allocations.

Comment: Ah, `std::unique()` - that's a really good choice (and I'd forgotten that there's a predicate version).  There's a tool in `<algorithm>` for every need!

Answer (score 0):

> It's about accessing `(&ch)[1]`. I think it should be legal, but I am not sure.

Yes, it is legal as long as you have null terminated string, i.e. the `size`-th character of the string is the null character. The reason is that `std::string::end()` returns an iterator that is one short of the element that holds the terminating null character when the string object does have a terminating null character. Hence, `(&ch)[1]` will not access anything beyond the terminating null character. You can verify that by printing the value of `&ch` as a debugging guide.

Here's a updated version of your posted code that prints additional debugging info.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

std::string remove_excessive_ws(std::string const &str)
{
   std::string result{ str };

   std::for_each(std::begin(result), std::end(result),
                 [](std::string::value_type const &ch)
                 {
                    std::cout << "pointer value: " << reinterpret_cast<void const*>(&ch) << std::endl;
                 });

   std::cout << "==========================\n";

   auto end{ std::remove_if(std::begin(result), std::end(result),
                            [](std::string::value_type const &ch)
                            {
                               std::cout << "pointer value: " << reinterpret_cast<void const*>(&ch) << std::endl;
                               return std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned>(ch)) &&
                                      (std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned>((&ch)[1])) || (&ch)[1] == '\0');
                            })
   };

   result.erase(end, std::end(result));
   return result;
}

int main()
{
   char const *foo{ "Hello   World!   "};
   std::string res = remove_excessive_ws(foo);
   std::cout << "\n\"" << res << "\"\n";
}
```

Here's its output.

```
pointer value: 0x600012be8
pointer value: 0x600012be9
pointer value: 0x600012bea
pointer value: 0x600012beb
pointer value: 0x600012bec
pointer value: 0x600012bed
pointer value: 0x600012bee
pointer value: 0x600012bef
pointer value: 0x600012bf0
pointer value: 0x600012bf1
pointer value: 0x600012bf2
pointer value: 0x600012bf3
pointer value: 0x600012bf4
pointer value: 0x600012bf5
pointer value: 0x600012bf6
pointer value: 0x600012bf7
pointer value: 0x600012bf8
==========================
pointer value: 0x600012be8
pointer value: 0x600012be9
pointer value: 0x600012bea
pointer value: 0x600012beb
pointer value: 0x600012bec
pointer value: 0x600012bed
pointer value: 0x600012bee
pointer value: 0x600012bef
pointer value: 0x600012bf0
pointer value: 0x600012bf1
pointer value: 0x600012bf2
pointer value: 0x600012bf3
pointer value: 0x600012bf4
pointer value: 0x600012bf5
pointer value: 0x600012bf6
pointer value: 0x600012bf7
pointer value: 0x600012bf8

"Hello World!"
```

---

#### Response to OP's comment

`std::string::end()` returns `std::string::iterator()`, which is a *LegacyRandomAccessIterator*. Please see the  [**Member types** of `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string#Member_types).

[*LegacyRandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) satisfies the requirements of *LegacyBidirectionalIterator*.

[*LegacyBidirectionalIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator) satisfies the requirments of *LegacyForwardIterator*.

[*ForwardIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) satisfies the requirements of *LegacyInputIterator*.

When a [*LegacyInputIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) is dereferenced, it evaluates to a `reference`. Now, you have to go back to [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string#Member_types) to see what that means. As you can expect, it is a reference and not a copy.

You can also use a non-`const` reference to be doubly sure that you get a reference and not a copy.

```
auto end{ std::remove_if(std::begin(result), std::end(result),
                         [](std::string::value_type &ch)
                         {
                            std::cout << "pointer value: " << reinterpret_cast<void*>(&ch) << std::endl;
                            return std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned>(ch)) &&
                                   (std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned>((&ch)[1])) || (&ch)[1] == '\0');
                         })
```

Comment: *You can verify that by [...]* – Standard reference? Also, Where is written that `find_if()` won't hand me a copy of the `char` instead a reference to it?

Comment: Whether it's legal to dereference `str.end()` depends on the standards version; only since C++11 has `str.data()` been required to have a null-terminator.

Comment: @TobySpeight, agree in principle. However, if the string object is a null terminated string, my answer is valid. I update the answer to make that clearer.